# a algebraic concept in reimannian geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry

let $(M,g)$ is a $C^{\infty}$ manifold with product form of  $M=R \times \Theta $
the
for each element  $\varepsilon (r,\theta )\in M$, the tangent space $T_{\varepsilon}M$ is natural isomorphic to $T_{r}R\oplus T_{\theta }\Theta $, the subspaces $T_{r}R$ and$T_{\theta }\Theta $ of $T_{\varepsilon}M$ are orthogonal to $g$.
i am pretty naive at riemannian geometry,can somebody please tell what this product means on vector spaces $T_{r}R$ and$T_{\theta }\Theta $.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Are you asking what the symbol $\oplus$ means in the expression $T_rR\oplus T_{\theta}\Theta$?

Comment: yes @MichaelAlbanese